# cocos2d-html5 onMouseDown, how to get converted position in browser?

Tags: cocos2d-html5

In cocos2d-html5,
I can get mouse event using this method,

```
onMouseDown:function( event ) {
    var loc = event.getLocation();
    console.debug( loc );
}
```

So in Chrome browser console, I can see the clicked location.
but, the location is not position of the cocos2d screen. 
the location is browser size relative position. I mean,

reference image~ 
[image]

But, I want to get cocos2d-screen relative position like this,

[image]

is there any way to get the position directly or 
any way to convert into the location?

My project is for browser based not simulator or phone.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

first, you can catch event,

```
onMouseDown:function( event ) {
    var rawLoc = event.getLocation();
    var loc = this.getOnPanelPos(rawLoc);

    //here you can do anything using converted loc

},
```

secondly, convert the coords.

```
 getOnPanelPos: function(loc){

        var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
        var canvasW = canvas.getAttribute("width");
        var canvasH = canvas.getAttribute("height");
        var scale = canvasH/960;
        this.bubblePanScale = scale;
        var scaleReverse = 960/canvasH;
        var paddingX = (canvasW - 640*scale)/2;
        var modifiedLoc = loc;
        modifiedLoc.x = modifiedLoc.x - paddingX;

        modifiedLoc.x *= scaleReverse;
        modifiedLoc.y *= scaleReverse;

        return modifiedLoc;
    },
```

Hope this help~

Answer (score 0):

You can use touch event to get what you want. This event can respond mouse too. It's a better cross platform resolution too.

```
onTouchesEnded: function(touches, event){
var location = touches[0].getLocation();
console.log(location);
this.changeAction(location);
}
```

This location is positive number in display area and negative number out of display area.

Like this:

```
cc.Point {x: 48.58870967741938, y: 107.66129032258064}
cc.Point {x: -286.491935483871, y: 71.37096774193549}
```

Ensure set the touch event on in your layer:

```
this.setTouchEnabled(true);
```